# Show toast if mp3 file there was not in SD card

Tags: file, mp3, sd-card, toast

In this class a mp3 file played from sd card, but if mp3 file not available
app give "force close"
i want cods that show toast if mp3 there was not in SD card(Not download) and back to previous activity.plase help me

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

getInit();
seekUpdation();
}


public void getInit() {  
seek_bar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek_bar);
play_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play_button);
pause_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause_button);
text_shown = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_shown);
play_button.setOnClickListener(this);
pause_button.setOnClickListener(this);
String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/music.mp3";
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
try {
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(filePath);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SecurityException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

    }
});
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
seek_bar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
}

Runnable run = new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {
    seekUpdation();
}
};

public void seekUpdation() {

seek_bar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
seekHandler.postDelayed(run, 1000);
seek_bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seek_bar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seek_bar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seek_bar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        if(fromUser){ 
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress); 
            seek_bar.setProgress(progress);
        }

    }
});
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
switch (view.getId()) {
case R.id.play_button:
    text_shown.setText("Playing...");
    mediaPlayer.start();
    break;
case R.id.pause_button:
    mediaPlayer.pause();
    text_shown.setText("Paused...");
}

 }

public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) { 
if(fromUser){ 
    mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress); 
    seekBar.setProgress(progress);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In IOException catch block place this code:

```
Toast.makeText(context,'No mp3 file found',Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
this.finish()
```

finish() will complete current activity and backs to the previous activity.

Comment: It means your platform does not support QCMediaPlayer. QCMediaPlayer provides extended APIs and interfaces to get and set MPD attributes for DASH protocol in compatible Snapdragon builds. So, this error should not affect on media playing in normal case

Comment: i have this problem only in android 5.0.2. in lower version no problem

Comment: use this in your project [QCMediaPlayer.java](https://github.com/fallowu/slim_hardware_qcom_media/blob/master/QCMediaPlayer/com/qualcomm/qcmedia/QCMediaPlayer.java)

Comment: There is no other solution?